# Is it justified for a teacher to refuse your project proposals just because he wants something unique?

Tags: computer-science, teaching, projects

I'm new here and am not sure whether this is the right place to post such a question or not so rather than downvoting just tell me I'll move the question (as I don't want to be banned for having low rep).

I'm currently in my 3rd semester of university majoring in Computer Science and this question is related to a course I'm taking - 'Data Structures and Algorithms'.

A little bit about the teacher -> graduated from the same university in which I'm currently studying last year and was hired to work here

So, the situation is that we have to submit a project (GUI based application made with Java and JavaFX) by 2nd January. Now, here are the problems:

The teacher **demands** we

- we implement every data structure we use from scratch (I have heard this is standard for this course).
- only use data structures he **hasn't** taught us and that all our projects should have unique data structures. Basically, no two groups/individuals can use the same data structure and as you can imagine this will lead to some people being stuck with highly obscure data structure whose implementation or ways of implementation either might not be available or not clear for the person to understand.
- use as many data structures as possible. I researched online on a few websites and found out that data structures are important but they are only a small part of the project there are a lot of other things.

As if that wasn't enough of a problem, he rarely responds to our queries on discord or through emails and the upper management doesn't listen to us.

I have also proposed a few project ideas but they were all rejected because there weren't enough data structures used or he didn't want us to use that data structure or some other reason. A few of these were:

- Text Editor (not enough data structures).
- Sudoku Solver (overused).
- Any project that used `stacks` to implement `history` and `backwards` and `forwards` navigation (don't use `stacks`).
- Todolist (too small project).

Now, I ask is it justified for a teacher to do such things just for getting a truly ***unique*** project?
We have barely 3 weeks left to start and finish our projects as not even one of use has gotten their projects approved yet.

**EDIT:**

Something happened last night, the students that were doing projects in groups collectively decided to not bother getting their projects approved anymore and are now going to go with whatever they want to, they will still use data structures but they are no longer going to strive to meet any of his criteria. They were extremely frustrated and being on the end of their rope they have decided on this and are saying that they will deal with it on the day of the evaluation.

Comment: "only use data structures he hasn't taught us" This sounds really weird. Java doesn't have five dozen alternative data structures. I'm sure he doesn't want that you copy&paste an example from his teaching and modify that, but write from scratch. (I'm *lost* in java if I can't do that. All my programs look the same, the structures have wrinkled skin and are missing a tooth or two. Terrible. ;-))

Comment: Our opinion on whether the assignment is justified or not means little because the instructor usually has the privilege of deciding how to assess learning. If all of the students are struggling, then the assessment seems too challenging for what students are capable of. I suggest making sure that you are performing on par or above average.

Comment: @Karl a lot of data structures don't exist in java so yeah we have to implement them from scratch like if someone wants to use TreeMaps even though they exist he/she has to implement that from scratch.

Comment: @Elodin yes, everyone is struggling but something happened last night please look at the edit

Comment: @Ak222 _a lot of data structures don't exist in java_: Such as?

Comment: You're asked to: Implement many untaught data structures. That seems easy. Here's a hint: Data-structure independence. (I won't use a technical term, since that seems akin to homework help.) You're also asked to: Implement a GUI-based application on top. Perhaps not too arduous. The tricky part: Finding an interesting application. Perhaps look to your teacher's research, see if there's something in their research that you can implement. That'd surely interest your teacher, otherwise it'd suggest their research isn't worthy of implementing/using.

Comment: @user2768 the teacher gave us an example of a project that we could do though he did say it would be hard. It was to implement djikstra's algorithm but here's the catch: whenever the user drags a node on the graph the distance between it and all other nodes should update and the algorithm should function based on the new distance. I tried searching online but there wasn't one that worked by updating the distance in real time it was more like it was constant throughout (the weight of the edges which was input at the time of the creation of the edge).

Comment: @Ak222 Surely there's a library for graphs and associated GUIs that'd support dragging a node? That'd probably get you a long way towards the teacher's example. (You didn't mention any restrictions on using such third-part libraries, so I presume that'd be okay.)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the standards are pretty high. It sounds like the instructor doesn't want you to be mediocre. It sounds like they are demanding some creativity.

Those are good things, actually.

It is hard to judge whether the standards are unreasonable or not but you would benefit by meeting them.

Are you permitted to brainstorm with other students? Do that if allowed. Have you asked for ideas from the instructor? Have you tried to take any of your original ideas and modified them to come closer to the standard? Alternatively, have you taken any really hard problems and tried to whittle them down to something that is doable and meets the standard?

It's good that you aren't being singled out, also. The farther you go, the higher the standards you will be expected to meet.

Comment: we are permitted to brainstorm and when we ask the teacher for ideas he says you can make whatever but follow the criteria. But the end problem is that in this course we study efficient implementation and usage of data structures. We have to implement data structures and in many cases a specific data structure is most efficient. The others can be used there are over 30 of them as far as I know but they are all meant for specific use purposes. We won't use a tree data structure where a stack would be the best option.

Comment: +1: High standards, no mediocrity, something interesting, requirements that'll lead to significant rewards, albeit, probably ill-suited to a class of mixed ability.

Comment: @user2768 the problem with our class is that most think Computer Science is too easy and are not even that interested in it as a career rather think of it as an easy money-making opportunity like most people in this field and while I may understand that it might be the teachers intention to weed some people out early on, it is also badly affecting the others that had some genuinely great ideas to look to other ideas just to be unique. And the reward part, well the project is valued at 15 marks out of 100 and for some reason the management decided for the final term assessment be valued at 50

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks if the instructor is justified in enforcing these requirements. Perhaps, perhaps not. I have an opinion, but that's not what I want to answer with.

You might consider attacking this assignment starting from the requirements rather than from the project. Look at a some data structures not covered in the class that you find interesting and think you could implement. Then design a project that calls for those data structures.

Note: three weeks is not a long time for an assignment like this. Try to be just ambitious enough in your data structure selection to satisfy the requirements.

Comment: the problem is with someone ending up with some obscure and really hard data structure because he wants a unique data structure in every project. Also, the bigger problem is that he has left no room for negotiation he is unwavering and says that this is how the 'professionals' work

Comment: @Ak222 Your comment addresses the OPs question as to whether the requirements are reasonable. My (non)answer is only a suggestion for a possible way to meet the requirements. (Parenthetically, this is not how professional programmers work.)